# How to have a for loop increment height and pos

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I am trying to have it so that my `drawRect` is created 13 times on the panel. This works correctly but I would also like it to start from a height of say `100` and increment up to `550`. I am not sure how I would add the incrementation of the height as I have the draw rect in a for loop already.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Draw extends JPanel
{
    Color rand;

    private int randRed() {
        int red;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        red = randomNumber.nextInt(255);
        return red;
    }

    private int randGreen() {
        int green;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        green = randomNumber.nextInt(255);
        return green;
    }

    private int randBlue() {
        int blue;
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        blue = randomNumber.nextInt(255);
        return blue;
    }

    int newRectPos = 0;
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int i = 0; i < 550; i ++)
        {

        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= 800; j = j + 60; int i = 0; i <= 550; i ++)
        {
            g.setColor(new Color(randRed(), randGreen(), randBlue()));
            g.drawRect(j, 0, 60, 550);
            g.fillRect(j, 0, 60, 550);
            repaint();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down votes? I suppose it is the nit-pickers back at it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

> for (int j = 0; j <= 800; j = j + 60; int i = 0; i <= 550; i ++)

You can write

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 800 && j <= 550; j += 60, i ++)
```

or as a nested loop of

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 800; j = j + 60) 
    for(int i = 0; i <= 550; i ++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define several variables in the first part of `for` loop statement and separate them by a comma `,`:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0;  //variable definition, more than 1 from the same type
     j <= 800 && i <= 550; //conditional
     j += 60, i ++ //after completing a loop in the for
    ) {
        g.setColor(new Color(randRed(), randGreen(), randBlue()));
        //fix this code accordingly
        g.drawRect(j, 0, 60, 550);
        g.fillRect(j, 0, 60, 550);
        repaint();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to do `&&` and instead just created it besides the int j.